# Split chemical sum formula into elementary components

Tags: r, split

I have chemical sum formulas e.g. C6H12ON2PS

I want them to order like this:

| Sum Formula | C | H | O | N | P | S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C6H12ON2PS | 6 | 12 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| C6H12NP | 6 | 12 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

My main errors are that if one Letter/Element is not there and when an element is there without an number which means I need 1 in the column.

I am not very good at R since I just started and I use a script from another person that uses those formats but I only have the text.

I tried

```
str_split(strsplit(as.character(Form), '(?<=.)(?=[A-Z])', perl=TRUE))
```

but this didn't worked when a letter was missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be safer to match against an actual list of elements from the periodic table so I gave it a try. Perhaps overkill and not super efficient:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# define sample data
x <- c("C6H12ON2PS", "C6H12NP")

# get list of elements in periodic table
elements <- PeriodicTable::symb(1:116)

# define regex to spot elements without quantity (implicitly "1")
name_regex <- elements |> 
  str_flatten(collapse = "|") %>%
  str_c("(", ., ")(?!\\d)")

# add implicit quantity "1"
x <- c("C6H12ON2PS", "C6H12NP") |> 
  str_replace_all(name_regex, "\\11")

# define regex that captures both element name and quantity
regex <- str_c(elements, "(?<", elements, ">\\d*)") |> 
  str_flatten(collapse = "|")

# define helper function to collapse rows (one for each match)
collapse_rows <- function(x) {
  if (all(is.na(x))) return(0)
  x |> discard(is.na) |> as.numeric()
}

# define helper function to convert search results to tibble
match_to_tibble <- function(m) {
  # drop first column (complete match)
  m <- m[, -1]
  
  # convert to tibble and collapse rows (one for each capturing group)
  m |> 
    as_tibble() |> 
    summarize(across(everything(), collapse_rows))
}

# extract quantities
x |> 
  str_match_all(regex) |> 
  map(match_to_tibble) |> 
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 116
#>       H    He    Li    Be     B     C     N     O     F    Ne    Na    Mg    Al
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    12     0     0     0     0     6     2     1     0     0     0     0     0
#> 2    12     0     0     0     0     6     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> # ℹ 103 more variables: Si <dbl>, P <dbl>, S <dbl>, Cl <dbl>, Ar <dbl>,
#> #   K <dbl>, Ca <dbl>, Sc <dbl>, Ti <dbl>, V <dbl>, Cr <dbl>, Mn <dbl>,
#> #   Fe <dbl>, Co <dbl>, Ni <dbl>, Cu <dbl>, Zn <dbl>, Ga <dbl>, Ge <dbl>,
#> #   As <dbl>, Se <dbl>, Br <dbl>, Kr <dbl>, Rb <dbl>, Sr <dbl>, Y <dbl>,
#> #   Zr <dbl>, Nb <dbl>, Mo <dbl>, Tc <dbl>, Ru <dbl>, Rh <dbl>, Pd <dbl>,
#> #   Ag <dbl>, Cd <dbl>, In <dbl>, Sn <dbl>, Sb <dbl>, Te <dbl>, I <dbl>,
#> #   Xe <dbl>, Cs <dbl>, Ba <dbl>, La <dbl>, Ce <dbl>, Pr <dbl>, Nd <dbl>, …
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Wounderful! Thank you very much, with some small modifications I could make it useable for me (I really don't need the whole table, but the idea is great).

Comment: Thanks for having a look at my answer. I really think @jblood94's answer should do the job for you though. If your issue is aggregating the results in a dataframe and you prefer the Tidyverse, try this code: `c("C6H12ON2PS", "C6H12NP") |> 
  CHNOSZ::makeup(count.zero = TRUE) |> 
  purrr::map(bind_rows) |> 
  purrr::list_rbind()`

Answer (score 5):

Using `CHNOSZ::makeup`:

```
CHNOSZ::makeup("C6H12ON2PS")
# C  H  O  N  P  S
# 6 12  1  2  1  1
```

We can use `data.table` to get a character vector of chemical compounds into tabular format:

```
library(CHNOSZ)
library(data.table)

compounds <- c("C6H12ON2PS", "C6H12NP")

formulas <- makeup(compounds, count.zero = TRUE)
formulas <- data.table(compound = compounds)[
  ,names(formulas[[1]]) := transpose(formulas)
]
print(formulas)
#>      compound C  H N O P S
#> 1: C6H12ON2PS 6 12 2 1 1 1
#> 2:    C6H12NP 6 12 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: Of course it had to be implemented somewhere already :P

Comment: Thank you, but it let's me with the same problem, that sometimes I dont have all elements

Comment: I think you want to make use of the `count.zero` argument. See the update.